# dplyr force one object to mask another

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
```

If I load these two packages I get a warning that, *"The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’: combine"*.

What's the correct way to force the dplyr `combine` object? These all seem to work. Is there a preferred syntax?

```
combine <- dplyr::combine      #1
combine <- dplyr::combine()    #2
combine() <- dplyr::combine    #3
combine() <- dplyr::combine()  #4
```

Comment: I wouldn't create a new function called combine in your global environment, instead just call `dplyr::combine()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `dCombine() <- dplyr::combine()`, although I am not sure if this is the best practice.